# 2 independent dropdown buttons

Tags: javascript, css, button, drop-down-menu

I need to achieve 2 things with these dropdown buttons [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2Yp5r/1/)

1. They need to work independently from one
   another. So basically what I'm trying to achieve is when you click
   on the first button the second button doesn't get affected and
   vice-versa. On my example when you click on one button the other one
   gets that border around and that shouldn't happen, it should be
   completely independent.
2. When one dropdown is active if the second one is clicked the first
   one should close automatically.

I hope my question makes sense.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is working mate: http://fiddle.jshell.net/2Yp5r/4

Basically 2 things:

1. Set only the clicked element as active, by using `$(this)` instead the general `$('.clicker')`
2. Close previous opened tabs, that's all commented below as well.

   $('.clicker').click(function(e) {

   ```
        //remove previously active style
   $(".clicker").removeClass('active');

   //check if this tab is not opened
   if( $('+ ul', $(this)).css('display') == 'none')
   {
       //hide previous opened tab
       $('.dropdown').not(this).hide();

       //add style to clicked element
       $(this).addClass('active');   
   }

       $('+ ul', $(this)).slideToggle(200);

       if($(e.target).attr('href') == '#') {e.preventDefault();}

       e.stopPropagation();
       e.stopPropagation();
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks. However if the first button is active and then u click on the second one the border is still displaying on the first. button. We're almost there I think ;)

Comment: That's right, I fixed this too..I'll update my answer see now: http://fiddle.jshell.net/2Yp5r/4/